# Android App Ad Integration - Best Approach

Tags: android, integration, ads

I've been looking at many posts on integrating ads into an Android application. There doesn't seem to be any straight forward answers but a lot of choices to pick from. I'm looking for advice on which one would be the best to use!!

I want to integrate ads into my application and looking for the best one to choose. There are lots of posts that give examples of these ads (e.g. AppsZoom, AdBuddiz, Admob, Adwhirl, MobFox, MobClix, etc....). From what I am reading, Admob seems to be the best approach. Would anyone have any thoughts on this as I don't want to waste time on looking into alternate solutions if they are not worth it.

I'm just looking for a nice clean, quick integration that could potentially generate a bit of money per install, per click or whatever the best approach would be.

Appreciate any comments and thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use Ad Mob, now known as Google Mobile Ads, because the integration is very easy (see https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html)

Knowing when to show ads is also extremely important, so I suggest you spend some time thinking about this, which is why I recommend using AdMob, as at this stage, you're better off spending your time thinking about when to show the ads than which ad network to choose (you can always do some A/B testing between networks in a later release of the app).

Comment: Hi @FreewheelNat, thanks very much for your response. I have implemented the AdMob and opted for interstitial ads as my research suggests that's the best approach. I have also put the ads at distinct break points in the app, not to disturb the users. This seems to work fine. One question is that once it works on my local device, does this mean that it will definitely work and start earning money once I upload to the Store? Also, do I need to do any work on the ad network or should I just go with the default until I know more about them? I really appreciate your help on this, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Appodeal, because they combines defferent ad networks and choose the best targeted ads to show. They currently have around 10-12 networks in their mediation plan through one API (www.appodeal.com).